# Creating Power BI Dashboard From AzDO Pipeline Build Stats Across Projects

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, powerbi

I apologize if this is a question that can be answered by looking at MS documentation, but I'm new to the Azure environment, and I've been looking through the documentation. I've been tasked by my team at work with creating a dashboard which will display various stats from AzDO pipelines calling our YAML pipeline framework. Other teams are using AzDO pipelines based on our framework to migrate applications from on-prem servers into Azure, and we want to know:

- How many times the pipelines have been run.
- The success rate of the pipelines.
- How long each run of the pipeline takes.

The biggest challenge here is that my team's framework is called by pipelines being run on many, many Azure projects across our enterprise. Because of this, it seems that I can't simply create an AzDO dashboard using Pipeline Analytics. I discovered the Odata API, and it seemed that I may be able to use it to query the analytics information that I want from the pipelines. I could then conceivably use the data returned through Odata in a Power BI dashboard. Unfortunately, I won't be able to get organization-level access to run queries across projects due to information access restrictions. My thoughts now are that I may be able to put a Powershell script into the pipeline framework, which would, every time pipelines based on our framework are run, write the necessary information (mostly from BuildOutcomes) into an Azure SQL database. I could then query the database in Power BI to display the metrics. I'm having trouble locating a way to call up the metrics that I need in Powershell, after digging through the documentation and Azure module commands.

Has anyone done what I am trying to do? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) information is not enough? You don't need to use a SQL Database; a Blob storage is also possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. Unfortunately I don't think this will work for me - I cannot get permissions to make API requests at the organization-level. What I need is to be able to put some kind of step or build job into our framework, that way when a new project uses our framework, it will automatically begin pushing analytics about its build pipelines into some type of storage or database.